# Function not working in jQuery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to animate a submit button when it is clicked. My function is:

```
    function displaySubmitting(submitBtn, defaultText, doSubmit){
      if (doSubmit == true){
        submitBtn.removeClass("disabled");
        submitBtn.html("<i class='fa fa-spin fa-spinner'></i> Searching...");
      } else {
        submitBtn.addClass("disabled");
        submitBtn.html(submitBtnTxt);
      }
    }
```

My variables are:

```
    var $contactForm = $(".contact-form");
    var contactFormMethod = $contactForm.attr("method");
    var contactFormEndpoint = $contactForm.attr("action");
```

And here is my submit function:

```
        $contactForm.submit(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();

          var contactFormSubmitBtn = $contactForm.find("[type='submit']");
          var contactFormSubmitBtnTxt = contactFormSubmitBtn.text();

          displaySubmitting(contactFormSubmitBtn, "", true);

          var contactFormData = $contactForm.serialize();
          var $thisContactForm = $(this);

          $.ajax({
            method: contactFormMethod,
            url: contactFormEndpoint,
            data: contactFormData,

            success: function(data){
              setTimeout(function(){
                displaySubmitting(contactFormSubmitBtn, contactFormSubmitBtnTxt, false)
              }, 500);
              $.alert({
                title: "Success!",
                content: data.message,
                theme: "modern",
              });
              $thisContactForm[0].reset();
            }
         })
     })
```

I can't seem to call the `displaySubmitting` function. My other alert function seems to be working fine. The form is a generic contact form.

Interestingly if I don't use the function it works.

```
//displaySubmitting(contactFormSubmitBtn, "", true);
contactFormSubmitBtn.html("<i class='fa fa-spin fa-spinner'></i> Submitting...");
```

And,

```
setTimeout(function(){
  //displaySubmitting(contactFormSubmitBtn, contactFormSubmitBtnTxt, false)
  contactFormSubmitBtn.html(contactFormSubmitBtnTxt);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Why do you think you can't call the function? Are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: Any `console.log` statements inside `displaySubmitting` is not working.

Comment: ... and no errors?

Comment: Why you use setTimeout arround function? It seems that is creating function

Comment: Do you have any error in your browser when you show the source ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No errors at all.

Comment: @Nirali I used set for showing the fontawesome animation for a short amount of time. Removing it does not change anything.

Comment: Only this `[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 65ms`

Comment: If you comment out the $thisContactForm[0].reset(); does it work then?

Comment: @OleHaugset It doesn't work.